# How to get ID of dropped object?

Tags: android

I'm creating some ImageViews dynamically. I want to know which object is dropped.
Please take a look at the line:

> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You've passed the card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

In this place I want to know what I've dropped (ID of ImageView would be great).
How to get it?

```
 private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    // called when the item is long-clicked
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // create it from the object's tag
        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)view.getTag());

        String[] mimeTypes = { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN };
        ClipData data = new ClipData(view.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);
        View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);

        view.startDrag( data, //data to be dragged
                shadowBuilder, //drag shadow
                view, //local data about the drag and drop operation
                0   //no needed flags
        );


        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
}

class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
    Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.table);
    Drawable targetShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hands);

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        // Handles each of the expected events
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            //drag shadow has been released,the drag point is within the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // if the view is the bottomlinear, we accept the drag item
                if (event.getX() > 500) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You've passed the card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                viewgroup.removeView(view);

                RelativeLayout containView = (RelativeLayout) v;
                containView.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `View.getId()` ?

Comment: It returns ID of View and not ID of ImageView or am I wrong?
How to match ID of View with ImageView?

Comment: Do you have to save the dragged object in a private field when initiating a drag and drop, to be able to retrieve the "dragged and dropped" object within the dropped DragEvent?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the documenation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html

> public abstract boolean onDrag (View v, DragEvent event)
>
> Added in API level 11 Called when a drag event is dispatched to a
> view. This allows listeners to get a chance to override base View
> behavior.
>
> Parameters
>
> **v** : The View that received the drag event. 
> **event**:    The DragEvent object for the drag event.
>
> Returns true if the drag event was handled successfully, or false if the drag event was not handled.
> Note that false will trigger the View to call its onDragEvent()
> handler.

So when you do `v.getId()`, it is going to return the id of the view that the user started drag operation on. If this happens to be the `ImageView`, it will return the id of it, or else the id of the view the user is dragging.

Comment: I can see that whichever object I drop the ID stays the same. I guess this is the ID of RelativeLayout. Why is that?

Comment: You said you are creating the `ImageView`s dynamically, right? When you are creating them, assign unique id's to them via `View.setId();`. Then check.

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, I needed to check that ID in onTouch.

Comment: `v.getId()` from `onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)` returns id of the destination/dropped into view's reference and not the dragged item

Comment: Do you have to save the dragged object in a private field when initiating a drag and drop, to be able to retrieve the "dragged and dropped" object within the dropped DragEvent?